# Sharing java doc on Google Drive

Tags: google-drive, html

I am working on an API and need to share the java doc with some people. I generated the doc and now it's inside a directory. From my computer if I click on the `index.html` file, it works as expected and opens as a web page. But when I upload the folder to Google Drive, clicking on `index.html` file does not open it as a web page but rather as a text file. Is there a way to get Google Drive to open the `index.html` as a web page?

Comment: Essentially, you want Google Drive to host your HTML file. This feature is no longer available.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible on Google Drive, it's not its purpose.

You might want to use something like [javadoc.io](http://www.javadoc.io/) or similar product, depending on your more specific needs.